# How to specify WLAN interface to apt-get install

Tags: raspberry-pi, apt

In my raspberry pi I have two mobile dongles then my RP shows two WLAN interfaces, one of them is connected to the internet (wlan1) but the other (wlan0) doesn't because is connected to my computer via AD-HOC. I need to install some packages but my pi always tries to get the packages via wlan0.

How can I specify the interface to 'apt-get install'?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you probably have a network configuration problem.  Check your default route.

Comment: Have you tried running the command "ifdown wlan0 && apt-get install XXXXX && ifup wlan0"? This would make wlan0 go down so the pi would use wlan1.